# android library in dependencies, but not exist

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
... // android { ... }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    ... // too long so i cant save edit!

    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j:4.0.4'
}
... //Kotlin and mavenCr..()
```

In bulid.gradle file dosent have any problem.
but in Java(Kotlin) code..

```
twitter4j.* // Unresolved Reference
```

Error like this: `Error:(23, 23) Unresolved reference: TwitterFactory` and another library works fine. only twitter4j dosent work. 
How do i resolve this?

Comment: could you show us your build.gradle file path ? or better all build.gradle file contents ?

Comment: I cant show more because the filter refuse my edits. sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if dependency path is correct.
2. Whether dependencies are being downloaded.
3. clean - build
4. Restart eclipse

.

Answer (score 0):

You synced your build.gradle file? Also try doing a clean and rebuilding the project.

Comment: You should post clarifying questions as a comment. There isn't enough in your post to qualify as an answer.